# Show that the stochastic process $X_n=(n+1) \mathbb{1}_{[n+1, \infty)}$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

In my exam on probability theory I got a question which I think probably contains an error since I simply cannot prove that $X_n$ is adapted. Moreover I cant even prove the martingale property. I also tried to modify the question tinkering with $X_n$ and the sigma fields to fix the problem so that I could make it a martingale but I was unsuccessful. Can somebody help! Is it really a martingale? And if not how can I modify the definition of random variables to make it a martingale.  Clearly the expectations are finite and equal to $1$ in this setting but other than that I cant prove anything.

[image]

Comment: Should it be $[n+1,\infty)$ for the partition?

Comment: @jdods that makes it measurable indeed but then I can’t prove the martingale property

Comment: @jdods I mean my idea was to show that the martingale property for the generator(in this case the partitions) of the $/mathcal{F}_n $since they are closed under intersection but I cant show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\left[n+1,\infty\right)$ belongs to $\mathcal F_n$, since it can be written as $\left[n,\infty\right)\setminus \left\{n\right\}$
 (the $\sigma$-algebras generated by $\left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\dots,\left\{n\right\},\left[n+1,\infty\right)\right\}$ or $\left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\dots,\left\{n\right\},\left[n,\infty\right)\right\}$ are the same, but the later is not a partition. Therefore, $X_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable.

Since 
$$
X_n=\left(n+1\right)\mathbf 1_{\left[n+1,\infty\right)}
=\left(n+1\right)\mathbf 1_{\left[n,\infty\right)}-(n+1)\mathbf 1_{\left\{n\right\}}=X_{n-1}+\mathbf 1_{\left[n,\infty\right)}-(n+1)\mathbf 1_{\left\{n\right\}},
$$
it suffices to prove that 
$$
\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{\left[n,\infty\right)}-(n+1)\mathbf 1_{\left\{n\right\}}\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}\right]=0.
$$

Comment: Isnt  $[n, \infty) \setminus \{n\}=(n,\infty)$

Comment: In the given discrete space, $(n,\infty)=[n+1,\infty)$.

Comment: Is it because we are are taking the complement wrt to $\Omega$ and by $[n, \infty)$ means all the naturals starting from n? This is the only why I can make sense of the setminus you used to show that $[n+1, \infty)$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}_n$ and if this is true, the notation is very weird

Comment: Davide is this even true $ \mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{\left[n,\infty\right)}-(n+1)\mathbf 1_{\left\{n\right\}}\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}\right]=0.$?

Comment: Usually $[n+1, \infty)$ is an interval that contains $n+1$; in this context it means $\{n+1,n+2,\dots\}$. I have to checked the last formula but here is some hint: $\mathbf 1_{\left[n,\infty\right)}$ is $\mathcal F_{n-1}$-measurable so it suffices to compute $\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{\left\{n\right\}}\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}\right]$. But $\mathcal F_{n-1}$ is generated by a finite partition and the conditional expectation with respect to such king of $\sigma$-algebra is not hard to compute.